# How can I work out who created an Azure resource, older than 90 days old?

Tags: azure

We have discovered some resources in a resource group in our Azure subscription and we have no idea how they got there. They seem to be unnecessary, so we will be deleting them, but before we do we need to know who created them (and then ask them why).

Unfortunately, there is nothing in the Activity Log pertaining to these resources (Application Insights resources). The Activity Log only goes back 90 days.

How can I find out who created these resources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. The only way to keep logs for longer than 90 days is to archive them to a storage account

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs#export-the-activity-log-with-log-profiles

or integrate it with Log Analytics

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-activity

If you don't have any of those configured, then there's no way to tell.

Comment: this still remains... kind of ridiculous that there isn't a property added to log this :\

Comment: really can't believe this... this isn't a log entry, it's a property of the resource... MSFT sometimes makes me desperate

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Bruno Faria. On Azure Portal, you could find when the resource is created. Maybe this will help you find you want.

[image]